# How can I track the time (official records) I spend outside the UK?

Tags: uk, uk-residents

Since there is no passport control while exiting the UK (e.g. via Heathrow), I have stamps on my passport for entries only. During the entry, passport officers ask me how long I have been outside the UK and I tell them.

I wonder how to track what is **officially** recorded. Is there a way?

Note: I'm a non-EEA citizen.

Comment: May I suggest acquiring some kind of information-retention technology you can operate yourself? _Pen and paper_ is a tested and true solution which is available at affordable prices in most locations.

Comment: @ahmedus It might be possible to ask Immigration to stamp your passport on exit as well

Comment: @Traveller: There's nobody to ask. One doesn't even _meet_ any immigration when leaving the UK.

Comment: If you booked your flights via email you could check them. The UK knows when you left but I doubt they'd tell you

Comment: You can request your immigration history https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration

Comment: @Traveller This could be an answer either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can request personal information about you that is held on the Home Office’s immigration records (this is also known as a ‘subject access request’). There are three types of request you can make, all are free of charge: Basic, Specific, or Detailed.

A Basic request takes 30 days and should provide you with the information you’re seeking in your question. You can apply online or in writing, and you must supply evidence to confirm your identity when applying.
https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration

Note: it does not specifically say so in the guidance on how to make a request, however I would imagine that the service is designed for one-off / infrequent requests, rather than after every trip to the UK.

Comment: Anecdotal experience: I tried the basic subject request, and got a pack containing only my previous long-term visa applications and annotations made by UKVI staff. It does not contain my entry/exit records. The OP might need the "specific" level, which allows one to specify what information they are seeking the Home Office to release.